# Cannot connect to VPN using 16.04 LTS, vpnc client

Tags: 16.04, vpnc

14.04 LTS worked fine with same vpnc client, same firewall settings. Cannot connect using vpnc in 16.04 LTS. Here is the output of `/var/log/sysvar.log using tail -f /var/log/syslog`:

[image]